# Exception to the general reference rule?

Tags: discussion, scope

Currently general reference is one of the standard reasons for closing a question. However, I want to propose an exception to this clause: The question should not be closed, if the general reference site can lead to spoilers to related works.

For example [Oghma's answer to "Where should I start with Star Trek?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/where-should-i-start-with-star-trek/4324#4324), he suggests reading up on histories of Spock and Kirk. If I ask about them here, the question would be closed. But, any sites I use may also contain spoilers about star trek tng. So, in such situations such questions should not be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider this an exception. If there's no obvious place to look for an answer, then it's not a general reference question. A question calling for information about X that doesn't spoil Y is not the same thing as a question for information about X. It's quite conceivable that there would be a general reference for X (typically the Wikipedia page for X) but not for X without spoiling Y. Then a question about X which clearly and prominently says not to spoil Y would be admissible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [flowchart](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) for deciding if something is "general reference".

The second question is "is the answer too slow to load, too hard to parse, or otherwise in need of improvement".  This is fundamental to the "general reference" system - there are many questions that are already answered somewhere, but on sites where the information is buried in an extremely long page (e.g. Wikipedia), obscured (e.g. Experts-Exchange), difficult to understand (e.g. a fragment of a forum discussion), badly worded, and so forth.

If your question explicitly says that you don't want spoilers of some type, then the "general reference" close type would only apply if there was a general reference that didn't include the spoiler - otherwise it's "in need of improvement" (with respect to your question).

Ideally, an answer to the question would answer it without the spoilers, and then link to the more detailed information with text like "for more information, some of which will be spoilers, see the Wikipedia page X".

IOW, I think this case is already excluded.